# css classes can't access it

Tags: html, css

I have some html and CSS but can't seem to get my head around classes. I have tried looking at w3schools and other sites but it wont seem to apply to mine for some reason.

```
<footer class="social">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="facebook logo"> 
    </a> 
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" alt="twitter logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt"">
    </a> 
    <p>
        &copy; 2014 Andy Taylor
    </p>
</footer>
```

And the CSS looks like this,

```
footer.social{ width:202px; height:20px; margin:0 5px; }
```

but I have also tried just .social{CSS} and that didn't work either.

Comment: I have switched to team treehouse now which seems more useful!

Comment: @AndyTaylor You can use Mozilla Developer Network as well :)

Comment: @AndyTaylor What is your main problem in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have left the closing of `<img />`.

```
alt="facebook logo" </a>
//----------------^^^
```

**Complete Code**

```
<footer class="social">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="" alt="facebook logo" /></a> 
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" alt="twitter logo"><img src="" alt"" /></a> 
</footer>
```

---

To reference everything in the footer, please use:

```
footer.social a { ... }
```

Comment: @AndyTaylor What exactly you wanna do?

Comment: Sorry I missed that out when I copied it, will update the question. But even when I close it properly it wont reference the class. The only way I can get it to reference properly if I include it in the <img> html like <img class="social"> but I want to reference it in the footer so it affects everything. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try when I get home :D

Comment: I won't don't worry always grateful for help! Quick question, if I wanted to access everything in the footer including the <p> would I just reference the CSS as footer.social{CSS here}?

Comment: `footer.social * {CSS}`

Comment: Cheers you have been a massive help!